# Definite integral, Green's function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

how would you tackle this integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^3 x}{1+r^2-2r\cos(x-5)}dx$$I presume some of you might notice the integrand (at least the denominator) is the Green's function - nearly, the rest is before the integral sign, but I didn't include it here. I've been trying to use Weierstrass substition here, but to no effect so far. I mean the integral doesn't look any much simpler. Or maybe I just don't know how to express $\cos(x-5)$ any different than $\cos x \cos 5 + \sin x \sin5$.

Comment: Is $r$ a function of $x$?

Comment: No, no, it's not.

Comment: Rewriting the integrand as $$\frac{3\sin x - \sin (3x)}{4(1+r^2-2r\cos(5-x))}$$ may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$I(r)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^3x}{1+r^2-2r\cos(x-5)}dx$$
with $r\ne1$. Clearly $I(1/r)=r^2I(r)$, so it is enough to find $I(r)$ for $| r|<1$.

Now, the change of variables $x=5+t$ shows that
 $$\eqalign{I(r)&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^3(t+5)}{1+r^2-2r\cos t}dt
=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{3\sin(t+5)-\sin(3t+15)}{1+r^2-2r\cos t}dt\cr
&=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{3\cos(t)\sin(5)-\cos(3t)\sin(15)}{1+r^2-2r\cos t}dt\cr
&=\frac{3\sin(5)}{4}J_1-\frac{\sin(15)}{4}J_3}$$
Where
$$J_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(nt)}{1+r^2-2r\cos t }dt$$
Now, for $|r|<1$ we have
$$1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^k\cos(kt)=\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r\cos t}$$
So, for $n>0$
$$J_n=\frac{2\pi r^n}{1-r^2}$$
So, for $|r|<1$
$$ I(r)=\frac{\pi((3r\sin(5)-r^3\sin(15))}{2(1-r^2)}$$
and for $|r|>1$ we use the fact that $I(r)=\frac{1}{r^2}I(\frac{1}{r})$.